# All Boolean Laws?

Tags: boolean-algebra

### Boolean Laws For Boolean Mathematics

1. Annulment

   A + 1 = 1

   A . 0 = 0

---

2. Identity

   A + 0 = A

   A . 1 = A

---

3. Idempotent

   A + A = A

   A . A = A

---

4. Double Negation

   A̅̅ = A

---

5. Complement

   A + A̅ = 1

   A . A̅ = 0

---

6. Commutative

   A + B = B + A

   A . B = B . A

---

7. De Morgon's Theory

   A̅+̅B̅ = A̅ + B̅

   A̅ .̅B̅ = A̅ + B̅

---

8. Distributive

   A (B + C) = AB + AC

   A + (B . C) = (A + B) (A + C)

---

9. Absorptive

   A + (A. B) = A

   A (A + B) = A

---

10. Associative

    A + B + C = (A + B) + C = A + B + C

    A . B . C = (A . B) . C = A . B . C

---

---

This is unknown law i found in here. (If this law has name pleas be kind and teach me.

1. Unknown 1

   A + A̅ B = A + B

   A . (A̅ +B) =  A . B

---

**My Question :** 
 *are these all Boolean laws that i would learn to solve Boolean mathematics? or there are another Boolean Laws that i missed? If there have please teach me.*

Comment: For A.(A̅ +B) = A.B, you can use the multiplicative law and identity law.

A.(A̅ +B) = A.A̅ + A.B = 0 + A.B = A.B. The second one does not have any law associated to it.

Answer (score 1):

The name of your unknown law is called as *Redundant Literal Rule*. For more information, I hope [this site](http://www.electrical4u.com/boolean-algebra-theorems-and-laws-of-boolean-algebra/) will help you. Hope it helps.

Comment: @BachiNirosh You can accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Those are the basic laws and theorems of boolean algebra.  If you are solving for a test, I'd stick with those.

Redundancy and Consensus are offshoots from other Laws.

Redundancy has two forms.
$$(X + \overline Y) • (X + Y) = X $$
$$X \overline Y + X Y = X$$

This is the form, you list:

$$(X + \overline Y) • Y = XY $$
$$X \overline Y + Y = X + Y$$

Consensus

$$(X + Y) • (\overline X + Z) • (Y + Z) = (X + Y) • (\overline X + Z)$$
$$X Y + \overline X Z + Y Z = X Y + \overline X Z$$

If you expand the terms, the last is absorbed into the first.

[Laws and Theorems of Boolean Algebra](https://www.mi.mun.ca/users/cchaulk/misc/boolean.htm)